# Flutter canvas. How to draw frustum or add a frustum to a basic graphic?

Tags: flutter, canvas, graphics, paint, frustum

I know how to draw a basic graphics,

```dart
  canvas.drawCircle();
  canvas.drawPolygon();

  ...
```

Is there any way to draw a frustum make it to 3d? Like those:

[image]

[image]

Comment: for a single ball, it may take more than 4 circles for shading. I will prefer using assets in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The 3D effect in the shapes that you posted most likely get their effect from shaders, not from a frustum. There are some limited abilities to use some shaders in Flutter, you can read more about it here: https://wolfenrain.medium.com/flutter-shaders-an-initial-look-d9eb98d3fd7a